Alternatives to using scripts to override browser behavior (back button)
I'm working for a business client who is providing information online regarding domestic abuse.  As part of the web experience, they want to provide (opt-in) functionality that helps protect users from abusive partners, by allowing them to quickly exit the site and prevent those partners from easily seeing what they were looking at.
As part of this we want to prevent someone from using the back button to see what was being viewed.
I am aware that messing with browser behavior is generally a bad idea, and why that's the case.
I am not specifically after JavaScript tricks to override the browser; I am seeking any solution that ideally prevents, or at least significantly makes more difficult, attempts to "go back" and see what was recently browsed.
For example, ideas so far:

Opening the main content in a new window that was spawned via a script, meaning that we can use a script to close that window and spawn a new one with unrelated 'safe' content.  Because it's a new window it would not have any 'back' action available.
Using HTTP redirects, so that when they exit they are sent on to another site we control which might forward them again - so that when someone goes 'back' they get the second site which auto-forwards to something else.

I'm not yet across the details of the implementation our vendor has so far used (I'm new to the project), but they do have something working that kinda works - however, when you go back the site we want to hide is partially rendered for a split second before the browser is sent on to a 'safe' unrelated site.
Please feel free to re-tag this question as appropriate.
Update 24-May-2024
For anyone grappling with this issue, this research discusses the broader topic, providing excellent background and discusses different techniques and their effectiveness.
https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3544548.3581078

Load real site in iframe of cover site. Hide iframe to quick exit.

Good idea @ry - The URL of the page that hosts the iframe would still be visible - something we'd need to work out, I guess.

Note that if you're dealing with tech-savvy abusive partners, they can always just open the browser's history viewer, which is maintained independently of the back button. This is pretty much exactly why private browsing exists: cookies, history, etc. aren't saved or persisted.

Agreed - I think the vendor is already taking steps regarding browser history.  At the moment the business client is looking for ways to avoid the flickering issue specifically.

Probably look at rewriting the tab's local history using history.replaceState, so that hitting back doesn't take you back to a site that then needs to send you on to a safe site but instead just navigates you to the that safe site directly.

This sounds like something that would be better done as a feature of browsers, a la in-cognito mode. Perhaps you and your client could work with the browser vendors.

Brainstorming...
All your navigations should open in a new tab to prevent history build up in a single tab...
<a href="" target="_blank">

Each page/tab can include a document event like below to overwrite itself with some abstract data, once abandoned...
document.onvisibilitychange=()=>{

 if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden'){

   document.body.innerHTML= 'Error: Cooking recipes disconnected...';

 }

};

